# iOS - UINavigationcontroller before and after UITabbarController

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, uinavigationcontroller

[image: iOS Navigation flow diagram in my app]

I am creating an iOS app with UINavigationController and UITabbarController.
First 2-3 screens using one navigation controller and next screens are embedded in tab bar controller. And each tab bar items uses separate navigation controllers.
When navigate in to one of the tab bar item, and on clicking back its navigated back to screen before the tab bar controller(HomeViewController2).

[HVC1 --> HVC2 --> TBC1 --> UIVC1 --> UIVC1.1 --> UIVC1.2, Now click Back Navigation button.. It will go back to HVC2]

I found that the first navigation bar is hiding tab bar item navigation controller's navigation bar. How can I use the individual navigation controller inside tab bar and on returning to the initial view in the tab bar, use the main navigation controller to navigate back to previous views?

Comment: actually what you want to do ? hide navigation bar item ?

Comment: Yes. Hide the main navigation when traversing through tab bar navigation controller.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change rootViewController of appdelegate's window instead of push to tab viewcontroller .

```
Window.RootViewController = yourTabViewContoller;
```

Comment: If I set like this, i cannot navigate back from Tab View to Home View right?

Comment: I need that navigation too as seen in the diagram